# If Statement Not working Correctly Won't Pass If Statement C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm making a magic 8 ball within the cmd. I want to ask the user if they would like to do. I want the program to keep asking questions until the user selects the letter E. If they try to shake before they ask a question then they will get an error.

The issue that I'm having is that when you enter A, you will enter a question. Then when I enter S right after, I get the error message searching RAM and it doesn't call my shake method.

So what is happening now is that I write "A". Then I enter my question and the options show up again. Once the options show up again, I select "S", and the ram statement comes up instead of going to the else statement. I need it to go to the shake method so then I can type "G" to get my answer.

```cs
public static string userAnswer = "";

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Main program!");
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Magic 8 Ball");
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
    Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
    Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
    Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
    Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
    Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball ball = new Magic8Ball_Logic.Magic8Ball();
    string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

    do
    {
        if (input == "S")
        {
            if (userAnswer != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Searching the Mystic Realms(RAM) for the answer");
                Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                //Call Method Shake()
                ball.Shake();
                Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        else if (input == "A")
        {
            userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
            Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
            Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
            Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else if (input == "G")
        {
            if (userAnswer != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Question Before Asking For An Answer.");
                Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                //Call Method GetAnswer()
                ball.GetAnswer();
                Console.WriteLine("(S)hake the Ball");
                Console.WriteLine("(A)sk a Question");
                Console.WriteLine("(G)et the Answer");
                Console.WriteLine("(E)xit the Game");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    } while (input != "E");
}
```

Comment: Move the code that prints your menu, (S) --> (E), to just below the `do` line.  Then you won't have to repeat it throughout your program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `string userAnswer = "";` in your declaration. but.. in your if you're checking it on `if (userAnswer != null)` but... it's never null

You should check `if (userAnswer != "")` Because if a string has the value `null` isn't the same as an empty string `""`

Comment: To add to his answer: or you can test if `userAnswer!=null`, but initialize this variable with `string.Empty`

Comment: You should use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace`.

Comment: @BogdanDoicin [String.Empty is the empty string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=netframework-4.8), not null.

Comment: ...which is why there’s some controversy about the use of String.Empty: Does it ever produce more readable code than “”? In my view, no: More clutter, less visually distinct, and it’s less difficult to be mistaken about what it means (though I can certainly imagine a novice assuming that “” and null “should be the same”).